# Seeking an algebraic solution of this problem

Tags: calculus, transcendental-equations

If $a$ is the solution of the equation $$xe^x=e^2$$
If $b$ is the solution of the equation $$x\ln x=e^2$$

Then what is $ab$?

I know the answer is $e^2$, using the symmetrical property of $\frac{e^2}{x}$,  $e^x$, and $\ln x$

But how can I do it algebraically?

Comment: What would you consider to be an algebraic proof ?

Answer (score 5):

From your first equation, $a e^a = e^2$.  If you define $b = e^a$, then $a = \ln(b)$ so $b \ln(b) = e^a a = e^2$.  And then $ab = a e^a = e^2$.

Comment: ok, this is valid... Easier than I thought.

Comment: You also have to prove that the equation $x \ln(x) = e^2$ only has one solution (just because $e^a$ is a solution of $x \ln(x) = e^2$ doesn't prove it's the $b$ we were initially given), which can be achieved by studying the function $x \mapsto x \ln(x)$ (which takes positive values only once).

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with the Lambert $W$ function, it can make this exercise almost trivial. (Granted, it's far from the most elementary solution, arguably even overkill, but once you become familiar with the function, this exercise just begs for its use.) You can read up more on the function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but it is essentially the inverse function to $f(x)=xe^x$. That is to say, if you know $xe^x = c$, then $x=W(c)$ (where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function), and $W(xe^x) = W(x)e^{W(x)} = x$.

Another easily-verified property of the $W$ function is $W(x \ln x) = \ln x$. We make use of this later.

Thus, using the $W$ function on both equations, we see

$$xe^x = e^2 \overset{W(x)}{\implies} x = W(e^2)$$
$$x \ln x = e^2 \overset{W(x)}{\implies} \ln x = W(e^2) \implies x = e^{W(e^2)}$$

By these, if $a$ is the solution in the first equation and $b$ in the second, then $ab$ is given by

$$ab = W(e^2) e^{W(e^2)}$$

From the definition as stated earlier, $W(x)e^{W(x)} = x$. Thus, $ab=e^2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$a$ is the (unique) solution of the equation 
$$F(a,\phi(a))= c$$
while $b$ is the (unique) solution of the equation
$$F( \phi^{-1}(b),b) = c$$
Then $b = \phi(a)$, $a=\phi^{-1}(b)$. Therefore
$$F(a,b) = c$$